# How to get points information when hovering over axis labels in highcharts using custom-events library?

Tags: highcharts, custom-events

I have a bar chart with labels. Is it possible to get the "points" data by hovering over said labels using custom-events library?

By points data I mean the variable from here:

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter(this: { points: any[] }) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through all series points and match a point with a label position. Example:

```
    xAxis: {
        ...,
        labels: {
            events: {
                mouseover: function() {
                    const points = [];

                    this.axis.series.forEach(s => {
                        s.points.forEach(point => {
                            if (point.x === this.pos) {
                                points.push(point);
                            }
                        })
                    });

                    console.log(points);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3xvgtw2c/

Comment: Where does the "pos" come from? I don't have that variable available to me.

Comment: Hi @droft1312, As you can see it comes from `this`. Could you recreate your current state in jsfiddle to show the problem?